# Clarification on foreign keys, SQL

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys

If I make it so that one of the attributes in my relation A references a foreign key of another relation B, is the attribute in A required to be the primary key for A (or part of the primary key for A)?

Also, my understanding is that in order to reference an attribute, the referenced attribute must be a key or unique. Am I then right is asserting that we couldn't reference part of a primary key (i.e if the primary key had two attributes we would need to reference both of them or neither, since by itself neither attribute is guaranteed to be unique)?

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key must reference a unique key of some sorts, whether it's a primary key or not. You cannot reference just part of a composite unique key, unless it's a unique key on its own right.

The referencing field(s) can be a unique key (making the relation a 1:0..1 relation, but needn't necessarily be one.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right in your understanding. Lets say you were storing information about dogs being washed at a doggy parlor, and you had two tables (tbl_dog, tbl_DogsWashed).

tbl_Dog has the columns (DogId,DogsName,Breed,OwnersIdentityNumber)

tbl_DogsWashed has the columns (DogsWashedId,DogsName)

If you linked the two tables together using the dogs name, you would risk the fact that two different dogs with the same name have had washes.

Rather, tbl_Dog would have the columns (DogsWashedId,DogId) and you would look up the DogId using the DogsName,Breed,OwnersIdentityNumber etc and populate the tbl_DogsWashed table with a primary key from tbl_Dog.